# Правила удержания аннотаций. SOURCE, CLASS, RUNTIME

Tags: java, аннотации

Что обозначают правила `SOURCE`, `CLASS` и `RUNTIME`, инкапсулированные в перечисление
`java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рассмотрим вопрос на примере аннотации `@Override`, которая указывает на переопределение метода.

Так выглядит `@Override` в своей реализации

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Override {
}
```

- `SOURCE` в данном случае указывает на то, что аннотация `@Override` (как и другая, к которой это правило будет применимо) будет "отброшена" во время компиляции.
- `CLASS` - как другое правило, указывает, что аннотация, к которой оно будет применимо, сохранится в файле с расширением `.class` во время компиляции, но **не  будет доступна** для виртуальной машины `JVM` во время выполнения.
- `RUNTIME` - как другое правило, указывает, что аннотация, к которой оно будет применимо, сохранится в файле с расширением `.class` во время компиляции, и **будет доступна** для виртуальной машины `JVM` во время выполнения.

Comment: А в чем смысл не отбрасывать, но делать недоступной для JVM? То есть `CLASS` имеется в виду.

Comment: @alexolut: Интересный вопрос. [Вот](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5971247/5330439), что мне удалось выяснить о `CLASS`.